# Query for checking if every cell is null in a column by id

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, case, window-functions

Below is an example table, I am trying to figure out a way to write a query to put a Y in every cell under READY if all of the STOCK cells are empty for each ID row. So a Y would only show up in the READY columns for ID 1 since OS is in one of the columns for each other ID.

| ID | STOCK | READY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  |  |
| 1 |  |  |
| 1 |  |  |
| 2 | OS |  |
| 2 |  |  |
| 2 |  |  |
| 3 | OS |  |
| 3 |  |  |

My first thought is to use a case statement but that puts a Y in every column that has blank STOCK instead of checking if all of the STOCK for each ID is empty. Any ideas how I could accomplish this?

```
SELECT ID,
STOCK,
CASE WHEN STOCK = '' THEN 'Y'
ELSE '' END AS [READY]
FROM TABLE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
select id, stock,
    case when count(stock) over(partition by id) = 0 then 'Y' end as ready
from mytable
```

The window count takes in account non-null values of `stock` in rows sharing the same `id`.

Comment: This sounded like it would work but for some reason I am getting all NULL values in my ready column

Comment: @jrdev12345 then it means that no id has its stocks all nulls. Note that null is a different thing than `''` (the empty string). If you want to consider both then `count(nullif(stock, '')) over(…)`